# Change width and height of image for Portrait and Landscape iOS orientation

Tags: ios, image, landscape, dimensions, portrait

I am using the following code on [my site](http://www.designlagoon.com) to reduce the size of a div on ipad portrait orientation and it is working successfully.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
   .mosaic-block {
      width: 226px;
      height: 135px;
    }
}
```

[image: iOS portrait]

However, when i change the orientation to landscape, the div keeps the same value instead of returning to the default larger size of the div.

[image]

If the site is loaded directly into landscape mode - it display correctly (in the larger size).

How can i make sure that the larger css div dimensions are applied when the user switches orientation from portrait to landscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your media query is correct - the ipad width/height doesn't change when it is rotated, only the orientation changes. Try updating your media queries to something like:

```
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  .mosaic-block {
    /* default size here */
  }
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  .mosaic-block {
    width: 226px;
    height: 135px;
  }
}
```

Reference: [CSS-Tricks media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Mr. JunkMyFunk.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me correctly target iPad portrait. It turns out that I was correctly resizing the .mosaic-block but should have been resizing the contained image.

I am using the [amazium framework](http://www.amazium.co.uk/) for responsive design and [mosaic.js](http://buildinternet.com/2011/03/mosaic-sliding-boxes-and-captions-jquery-plugin/) for the animated rollovers. Here is the complete HTML:

```
<div class="mosaic-block fade">

<a href="image.jpg" rel="shadowbox" target="_blank" class="mosaic-overlay details"
title="Title">
        <h4>A title</h4> 
        <p><span>Subheading:</span></p>
        <ul>
            <li><p>Some text</p></li>
            <li><p>Some more text</p></li>
            <li><p>Even more text</p></li>                                                              
        </ul>   
</a>
<div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="backdrop_image.jpg" class="max-image"/></div>
```

Amazium uses the .max-image rule to alter the image size at different resolutions:

```
.max-image  { width:100%; height:auto; }
```

My solution has been to set a specific image size for .max-image on ipad portrait:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
.max-image {
width:286px;
height:171px;
}
}
```

Many thanks for the advice Mr. JunkMyFunk.